# Tracking SQL Calls From MS Access to MySQL

Tags: mysql, ms-access, odbc, trace

I'm trying to 'see' the SQL statements that are sent from MS Access 2003 to MySQL via ODBC.

I've tried ODBC Tracing, but it's painfully slow, producing very large log files which are very difficult to read.

For example, and insert looked like this:

```
"INSERT INTO  `tracking`  (`contract_id`,`bp_id`,`csi_1`,`csi_2a`,`csi_2b`,`csi_code`,`item_number`,`csi_code_display`,`csi_name`) 
VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)\ 0"
```

It doesn't show the values, I think they are coded separately as SQLBindParameters, but I can't make out the values in those either.

Is there an alternate/better method that I can use to simply see the full SQL statements?

MTIA

Comment: question: why are you using MySQL as a backend to MS Access? Wouldn't SQL Express be a better fit?

Comment: How SQLE fit better pls?

Comment: ps: I chose MySQL coz I had some familiarity with it already, plus I need to link a website to the database at a later date.

Comment: For one, MySQL is not throttled on number of connections, whereas SQL Server Express is. Nor is the size of the MySQL data store limited. And it's not from Microsoft so using it is helping keep variety in the software ecosystem.

Comment: @David W. Fenton: "MySQL is not throttled on number of connections, whereas SQL Server Express is." -- you are perpetuating myths. "Let me repeat for clarity THERE IS NO WORKLOAD GOVERNOR IN SQL SERVER EXPRESS EDITION." (http://blogs.msdn.com/euanga/archive/2006/03/09/545576.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

[MySQL Proxy](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Proxy) should do what you're after.

Comment: Thank you.... but there wouldn't be a Windows based GUI tool like this, would there?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why this question popped up today in the "new questions" list, but it did, and I just Googled "sql profiler for mysql" and came up with this:

http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/using-new-query-profiler.html

I don't know if it is better, or if it works with the version of MySQL used by the original question, but I thought it might be useful to others who came to the question.

Comment: Thanks David, trying it out. :)

Comment: Be sure to report back in a comment if you find it helpful.